# Scrape Incoming new telegram channel message

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I've seen a lot of telegram **scraping** code that scrapes all history messages but is there a way to scrape the incoming new message? E.g. Start the program and it will wait for the newest incoming message and just output the latest message and not scraping the whole entire history, and yes incoming messages not the last message on the channel. Thank you

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync

# Remember to use your own values from my.telegram.org!
api_id = ...
api_hash = '...'
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats='channel_name'))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    print(event.raw_text)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: How would you wait for the latest message?  And the word is "scrape".  "Scrap" means to throw away as trash.

Comment: My bad on the wording, I'm trying to run the program to just start and anticipate new messages but what this does this code I found on TG site is just scraping everything and even some weird instagram handle from an empty new group, but yeah I just want it to anticipate and output the latest incoming message

Comment: That's the problem.  There's no "event" protocol to get notified of new messages.  The best you can do is keep probing, checking whether the current state matches what you already knew.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping Telegram Messages in Telethon Using Channel ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69388729/scraping-telegram-messages-in-telethon-using-channel-id)