# Scraping Telegram Messages in Telethon Using Channel ID

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am trying to scrape new messages from a Telegram channel I am a member of. I have the ID and invite link but not the actual address.

The code below works fine with the Reuters channel I am using to test.

Is it possible to use the ID or invite link instead of the actual address?

```
import configparser
import json
import re
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import (GetHistoryRequest)
from telethon.tl.types import (
PeerChannel
)

api_id = '*******'
api_hash = '**************************'
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

user_input_channel = 'https://t.me/ReutersWorldChannel'

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=user_input_channel))
async def newMessageListener(event):
    newMessage = event.message.message
    print(newMessage)

with client:
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the chat_id of the correct channel, then yes you can get the messages.

```py
import configparser
import json
import re
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import (GetHistoryRequest)
from telethon.tl.types import (
PeerChannel
)

api_id = '*******'
api_hash = '**************************'
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

chat_ids = [-100123562772, -55627728]

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=chat_ids))
async def newMessageListener(event):
    newMessage = event.message.message
    print(newMessage)

with client:
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks Prashant